# Etymlogy of "Bedürfnis"

Tags: etymology

I've tried to search on Google for the etymology of this word but I couldn't find it (or at least I couldn't understand that it was an etymology since it was written in German).

*Bedürfnis* should mean something that I need – a desire (etwas was ich brauche).

The strange stuff is that the *be-* prefix in German is often used to handle the accusative (correct me if I'm wrong) but the verb *[dürfen](http://it.bab.la/dizionario/tedesco-inglese/duerfen)* means something like "*I can*".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Bedürfnis` is a derivative of `bedürfen` with the suffix `-nis`. According to [DWDS (bedürfen)](http://dwds.de/?qu=bed%C3%BCrfen) and [DWDS (dürfen)](http://dwds.de/?qu=d%C3%BCrfen) the root of `bedürfen` and `dürfen` is

> Old High German: *thurfan* / *bithurfan* = in need of something or in general

The meaning of the prefix `be-` is unclear in that setting.

One of these two, `thurfan`, developed into another meaning:

> Middle High German: *durfen* = having reason
>
> New High German: *dürfen* = having the right to

while the other, `bithurfan`, kept its meaning.

Answer (score 3):

"einer Sache bedürfen" means to need sth. As the verb is used with a genitive object it is on the wane in written language. It is no word of colloquial language. There are two nouns,
Bedarf and Bedürfnis. The etymology of these words does not help much. The older wordforms
don't shed more light on these words than that they express need or what is necessary.
Bedarf is a current word today:

- der Bedarf an Rohstoffen / Erdöl/ Energie.
  Bedürfnis is not so common. It is used in polite formulas such as
- Es ist mir ein Bedürfnis, Ihnen meine Bewunderung auszusprechen.

Sometimes you find an older name for public lavatory/WC/toilet: Bedürfnisanstalt.